# Width of UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

I have a UITextfield in a UITableViewCell. I want the width of the UITextfield to be equal to the width of UITableViewCell. Refer to screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot: The text field width that I want]

## I have tried the following but it did not work:

- Add Auto Layout constraints: leading, trailing, top and bottom.
- Ctrl-Drag UITextfield to ContentView and selected 'Equal Width'.

Applying any constraints causes the width to shrink, as seen in the screenshot below.
[image: Screenshot: Applying the Auto Layout constraints cause the width to shrink]

## Swift 3 codes in custom table cell

```
func configure(text: String, placeholder: String) {
    emailTextField.text = text
    emailTextField.placeholder = placeholder
    emailTextField.accessibilityValue = text
    emailTextField.accessibilityLabel = placeholder
    emailTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
}
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

## Attempt 1

- Remove existing textfield
- Add a new texfield
- Apply leading, top, trailing and bottom with 8 points.
- Build and run the app in Simulator shows that the width still doesn't expand to the width of UITableViewCell.

[image: Attempt1]

Comment: can you please upload a picture of your constraints ? also try setting the with of the text field to be equal to the width of the UITableViewCell

Comment: You don't need to add "UITextfield to ContentView and selected 'Equal Width'." as you have already added all other 4 constraints. Also, check if you have added constraints to your tableview.

Comment: @SNarula I tried adding the four constraints first but that didn't work. Then I removed the four constraints and added Equal Width, which still doesn't work.

Comment: @SNarula I have added the four constraints to UITableView so that it is positioned under the label "Team Members" and 20 points from the right.

Comment: @J100 I'm having the same problem. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: @Malaise Sorry I can’t remember what I did to solve it.

Comment: I had this same problem, and I believe it was because of a custom UITextField I was using. I needed to lower the hugging priority to 249, and then it extended across the entire cell.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add constraints as per image showing, It works correctly.

Comment: This is the Auto Layout constraint that I had set up but the width of the text field still doesn't expand as I want in my first screenshot.

Comment: remove textfield and do it fresh then check.

Comment: Removed textfield, add a new one and applied your suggestion. But still not working. Refer to screenshot above.

Comment: still getting same issue?

Comment: can attach textfield constraints screen shot?

Comment: yep, I added to my question.

Comment: constraints are correct. Are you any third party code for textfield?

Comment: I added some codes that I have in my custom cell file.

Comment: The textfield width shrinks even further because there is no text or placeholder text.

Answer (score 0):

Add Auto Layout Constrains:Leading,Top and Width of the text field should equal to superView width and adjust the Multiplier according to it.

Hope it works, sorry if I'm wrong.

I have added the two different simulator screenshots for yours reference.

[iPhone 7 Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyRRJ.png)

[iPhone SE simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmE3V.png)

Comment: It doesn't look like you placed a textfield in a UITableViewCell.

Comment: Ya I know But its working dude.i have edited my answer check it out

Comment: I know but the issue I have is when the text field is in a UITableViewCell. Other text fields that I have that are not in UITableViewCell is behaving fine.

Comment: Let me Check again ,Because its working fine for me.

Comment: Check My answer @Jason100,i have added the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and solved it by reducing the horizontal content hugging priority to 249.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622485-setcontenthuggingpriority
https://krakendev.io/blog/autolayout-magic-like-harry-potter-but-real

[image: Interface Builder Properties]